# Search for sequence of items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is there an easy way to search for a sequence of strings in a list? For example:

```
testlist = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,a,b,c,d,j,k,j]
```

and I want to search for the sequence `abc` and getting the index returned. So to clarify if the string I want to search consists of more than one element of the list. For some context: I have a list with datablocks and I want to find out how big each datablock is therefore searching for a reoccuring string in the list.

Comment: convert to string and search.

Comment: I found Knuth's paper "[Fast Pattern Matching in Strings](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.93.8147)" an exciting read.

Comment: is there another way? i need the position of the reoccuring string.

Comment: i´m going to read "Fast Pattern Matching in Strings" thanks !

Comment: this is a list of variable names, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

There are many good [string search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm): KMP, Boyer-Moore, Rabin-Karp. You can use the builtin `str.index` function on `''.join(L)` if you are dealing with characters (`str.index` implements Boyer-Moore algorithm in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).

But in most cases, the naive algorithm is good enough. Check every index of the `haystack` to find the `needle`:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, j, k = [object() for _ in range(9)]
>>> haystack = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, a, b, c, d, j, k, j]
>>> needle = [a, b, c]
>>> for i in range(len(haystack)-len(needle)+1):
...     if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle:
...             print(i)
... 
0
7
```

The complexity is O(|haystack|*|needle|).